# How to change text of button while function is running

Tags: ios

I have the following function that runs whenever a button is pressed:

```
func deletekeyPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    while(textDocumentProxy.hasText()) {
        (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
    }

    for _ in 1..<2000 {
        (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
    }

}
```

To prevent user from thinking the program is crashing I want the text of the delete button which normally says "Delete All" to "Deleting..." or even better have the title alternate between the following states: "Deleting", "Deleting.", "Deleting..", "Deleting..."

So far I have tried putting a `setTitle()` for `UIControlState.Normal` at the beginning and end of the function in order to make the text say "Deleting" when the function is running.

This makes my function look like this:

```
    func deletekeyPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    sender.setTitle("Deleting...", forState: .Normal)

    while(textDocumentProxy.hasText()) {
        (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
    }

    for _ in 1..<2000 {
        (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
    }

    sender.setTitle("Deleting...", forState: .Normal)
}
```

However, nothing is happening. How do I implement this solution?

Update One: I implemented Aaron's solution like this:

```
 func deletekeyPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    NSLog("-------------------")
    NSLog("Pressing delete key")

    sender.setTitle("Deleting...", forState: .Normal)
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = false



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    NSLog("Starting delete function")

        while(self.textDocumentProxy.hasText()) {
            NSLog("Deleting 3 times")
            (self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
            (self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
            (self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
        }

        for _ in 1..<2000 {
            (self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
        }

        sender.setTitle("Clear", forState: .Normal)
        sender.userInteractionEnabled = true

        NSLog("Finishing delete function")
    }
```

However I run into the following problem. The solution partially works in the sense that the button text will say "Deleting..." until the code inside `dispatch_async` finishes running. But the problem is the UI of textfield in which the text is being deleted is not updated as soon as the code inside `dispatch_async` finishes running. This leads the delete button's text to say "Deleting..." for a short amount of time (as long as it takes for the code to finish running) even if the UITextfield has not updated itself to show the change from the code.

Here is a video of the problem:

[image: bugdemo]

Notice how the delete function finishes calling way before the screen updates.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the UI only draws after the main run loop completes. So your command to change the text has no effect until after the work is done.

One simple resolution is to schedule the deletion work at the end of the main queue:

```
func deletekeyPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    sender.setTitle("Deleting...", forState: .Normal)
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = false

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        while(textDocumentProxy.hasText()) {
            (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
        }

        for _ in 1..<2000 {
            (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
        }

        sender.setTitle("Deleted!", forState: .Normal)
        sender.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, what do you mean by "the main run loop completes"? Is this referring to whatever is being executed in the function therefore saying that the UI does not update until a function is finished calling?

Comment: Also something is strange is happening with this. The solution partially works in the sense that the button shows the text "Deleting..." until the code inside `dispatch_async` is finished running but for some reason the UI does not show the text as being deleted as soon as the code inside dispatch_async finishes running instead there is a noticeable pause. What this results in is the button saying "deleted!" before the text is actually deleted. I will post a video of this in a second.